# Rotating a UICollectionView leads to error

Tags: swift

When I rotate the device with a UICollectionView I get an error:

the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

I think that this mistake is within my UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout where I try to set the height

```
    if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape {
        height = min( Constants.screenWidth, Constants.screenHeight )
    }

    return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: (height - 300) / 1 )
```

as you can see I've tried to alter the height for the orientation, but ultimately this does not change as I thought it should.

Complete code is in this GitHub link: https://github.com/stevencurtis/CollectionViewRotate

I want to stop getting this error, and ultimately because the height is incorrectly set when I rotate the device the image is larger than the bounds of the view.

How can I set up my flow layout so this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the screen is irrelevant.  What you really care about is the height of the `collectionView`.

Use:

```
let height = collectionView.bounds.height
```

By using that value, the `height` will be correct when you rotate the phone without your having to check for it explicitly.  You'll still want to adjust for `insets` if you have any.

You should also use `collectionView.bounds.width` for the `width` in place of `view.bounds.width`.